# Movie in which kid with a leg problem falls in a sewer accident and goes to a parallel universe

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a movie in which a kid fell in a sewer accident/challenge and ends up in a different universe. I remember the kid having a problem with one of his legs some sort of iron staff was surrounding his leg from the knee down.

Comment: How is this a duplicate of a question that was asked 5 months ago and not vice versa?

Comment: Age of a question doesn't really play into it when closing as a duplicate. Instead we look for the quality and the answer on the duplicate is better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Warriors of Virtue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warriors_of_Virtue) (1997).

> Ryan Jeffers suffers a disability to his leg, preventing him from
>   trying out for sports and is instead a waterboy to the school's
>   football team. He has a crush on a girl at school, but it happens to
>   be quarterback Brad's girlfriend, which earns him ire from the popular
>   kids. Ryan is an avid comic book reader and dreams of adventure,
>   hiding his depression over his leg from his mother. One day, Ryan
>   meets with Ming, the owner of his favorite restaurant, who gives him a
>   manuscript of Tao, representing the five elements; Earth, Fire, Water,
>   Metal and Wood, and advises him to live no matter what his physical
>   limits are. That night, Ryan and his best friend Chucky are met by
>   Brad and his friends who want to initiate them with their group. They
>   are led to a water plant where Ryan must cross a narrow pipe to sign
>   his name on a wall on the other side. Ignoring Chucky's warnings, Ryan
>   attempts to do it. But a water pipe opens up, throwing Ryan into the
>   water.
>
> Ryan wakens in a forest and is attacked by strange creatures, he is
>   rescued by a strange creature from the lake and runs, realizing that
>   his leg now works. He meets Mudlap, a diminutive creature who leads
>   him to Elysia.